# Maven Eclipse Runtime Plugin Dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, m2e

We have a multi-module maven project that was recently converted from Ant+Ivy. One of the modules is a legacy custom pluggable component which looks for plugins on the classpath and loads them. Another module in the multi-module project is a plugin implementation that is run by the aforementioned plugin.

When running our custom application server from an eclipse run configuration, we must include each of our plugins on the classpath. As we build within the eclipse workspace these plugins are not compiled to a jar. Hence, there is no jar artifact to include.

If I add the plugin module project as a dependency in the eclipse run configuration, its transitive dependencies (supplied by Maven) are not inherited. Hence, class not found exceptions occur when the plugin is found and loaded by the Application Server.

The problem here is that upon importing the multi-module project, the m2e plugin does not set the maven container to be exported. Thus the missing transitive dependencies.

Is there any way to make this work whilst still running in eclipse using "build in workspace" for both the Application Server component and its plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Ivy is just a dependency management tool where as Apache Maven is a software project management.

Means It can handle all process in software development like compiling,building it to jars, search for depencies,linking, etc.

you no need to give your jars in classpath instead put it in your local repository or edit the pom.xml to fetch from remote repository.

this link http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/use/makepom.html